# ¿Cómo obtengo el registro según el id document en firestore y angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Yendo al punto, lo que quiero es según un id de documento que seleccione me despliegue solo la información de ese documento.

El id de documento es `2Hu84dRXVzBV2HjEdSCY` y me quiero traer solo la info de ese id:

```
console.firebase.google.com
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
service.ts
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
importaciones service.ts
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
component.ts
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
importaciones component.ts
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me trae, pero quiero que solamente me traiga el del id anteriormente mencionado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias y espero a ver sido claro con mi inquietud.

Comment: YA LO SOLUCIONE.

Comment: como lo conseguiste?? Necesito hacer lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const doc = this.firestore.collection('productos/').doc(docId).get()
    doc.subscribe((snapshot) => {
      const prod = snapshot.data();
      if (!prod) {
        console.log("Error no existe la llave")
      } else {
        console.log(prod['humor'])
        console.log(prod)
}});
```